# how to implement Within function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
within :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> a
```

that takes a tolerance, that is, a number
epsilon and an infinite list of numbers, and
looks down the list to find two consecutive numbers in the list that differ by no more than epsilon it returns the second of these. (It might never return if there is no such pair of
consecutive elements.) For example,

```
within 1.0 [1.0 ..] = 2.0
within 0.5 ([1.0, 32.5, 17.2346, 10.474, 8.29219, 8.00515]
++ [8.0, 8.0 ..])
= 8.00515
```

Comment: So... What's your question?

Comment: I actually don't know how to take 2 elements at a time and check if they differ by no more than epsilon. If I write something like check x y e = abs(x-y)<=e I don't really know how to use it in writing within function

Comment: I'm not at my PC, but I've written an answer about taking two elements of a list earlier today. It might be helpful. Basically use `within eps (x:y:xs) = ...`. However, you should think about the function's behaviour if the list isn't infinite and/or doesn't contain a fitting pair.

Comment: Here is some inspiration: this function takes a list and returns a list of pairs of consecutive elements `ap zip tail :: [a] -> [(a,a)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell, a list is just another data structure, perhaps with some (in my opinion) confusing notation. With any data structure, you can use pattern matching. When you're only working with lists, you have three possible things in a pattern:

- A variable, like `x`.
- A constructor applied to zero or more patterns,

  - like with `(:) x xs` (or perhaps more familiarily: `x:xs`),
  - or `[]`

Note that, in patterns, you apply constructors to *patterns*. It's perfectly allowable to write `(:) x ((:) y ys)` (more commonly written as `x:y:ys`), which matches any list of at least two elements, and assigns the first element to `x`, the second to `y`, and the remainder of the list to `ys`.

The skeleton of your `within` function would look something like this:

```
theFunction theList = case theList of
                          x:y:ys -> if canGiveAnswer x y
                                        then buildAnswer x y
                                        else theFunction (y:ys)
```

Here, `theFunction` tries to match its input with the pattern `x:y:ys`, checks whether `x` and `y` are sufficient to give an answer, and do so when it can, or restart itself (`theFunction (y:ys)`) with the first element of the list removed.

You can write this more tersely like

```
theFunction (x:y:ys) = if canGiveAnswer x y then buildAnswer x y else theFunction (y:ys)
```

or even

```
theFunction (x:y:ys) | canGiveAnswer x y = buildAnswer x y
                     | True = theFunction (y:ys)
```

Of course, in your case, you need an extra argument:

```
within :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> a
within epsilon (x:y:ys) | canGiveAnswer x y epsilon = buildAnswer x y epsilon
                        | True = within epsilon (y:ys)
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out what `canGiveAnswer` and `buildAnswer` are supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful! :D